# Busybox: how to quit Busybox and/or shut down computer

Tags: 18.04, busybox

I am on a terminal looking ("pre-boot") screen, in a utility/program called Busybox.
By pre-boot, I mean that I am not booted into the GUI of an operating system.  My computer loaded this utility/program instead of booting into the operating system.

How do I exit Busybox and shut down the computer?

Here is a web page that shows the commands:
https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

I couldn't find any quit or exit command.

Comment: You can always just tell the linux kernel to shutdown (ie. SysRq command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s `poweroff` or `poweroff -f`.

Also, `ash` does have an `exit` command, but the resource you mentioned is for the `busybox` binary, not the shell.

Comment: Thanks.  Was very helpful and to the point.  Put an end to a frustrating day for me.